# How do I properly plot data extracted from a scope as .csv file

Tags: python, matlab, csv, plot, gnuplot

I just extracted a .csv file from a scope, which shows how a signal changes in the time duration of 6 seconds. Problem is that I can't come up with a proper way of plotting this signal, without things getting mushed together.

Mushed together like this:

[image: Matplot screen shoot]

The .csv file is [here](https://ufile.io/12a6).

The signal goes through four stages, which I want to show with the plot, without it being to mushed together? How do I plot it?

More info about the signal:

The signal is a PWM signal that changes frequency. Either plotting the PWM signal vs. time, or the frequency of the PWM signal vs time, would be plot representation I would be /seeking for.

Comment: "The signal goes through four stages, which i want to show with the plot, without it being to mushed together?" - Can you describe what you mean by mushed together?

Comment: matplotlib does provide a means to interactively zoom in to a rectangle.

Comment: I added a image with the mushed

It could be nice to have a plot that shows the data properly in the plot, and don't need to be adjusted

Comment: I have given a possible explanation below. Also, I know this is not related, but what plotter are you using? Seems interesting :-) !!

Comment: The data appears to change in frequency over time, so It might make more sense to plot this rather than the raw data.

Comment: @R.S.NikhilKrishna The plotter i am using is a Logic analyzer i bought on ebay.. Salea Logic analyzer.

Comment: @MartinEvans The pwm signal that I ouput does change in frequency, actually plotting the change in frequency could also be a good way of representing the 4 stages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rudimentary analysis, you could do the following using a `deque` to process a sliding window of values:

```
from collections import deque
import csv
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


maxlen = 20
window = deque(maxlen=maxlen)

with open('12a6-data_extracted_2.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(csv_input)

    freq = []
    x = []

    for v1, v2 in csv_input:
        v1 = float(v1)
        window.append(v1)

        if len(window) == maxlen:
            x.append(v1)
            freq.append(maxlen / ((window[-1] - window[0])))

    plt.plot(x, freq)
    plt.show()
```

This would give you an output looking like:

[image: Frequency]

Comment: I think this is the best way to represent it... 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

### Zoomable plot with Gnuplot

Your problem is that you are plotting this with linear interpolation, with Gnuplot you plot digital data with the `with steps` style. If you use the `wxt` terminal (some other terminals also work) you get a zoomable plot, e.g.:

```gnuplot
set term wxt
set key above
plot 'foo.csv' with steps title columnhead
```

Results in:

[image: Properly "stepped" pwm signal]

Or to plot a subsection of the data:

```gnuplot
set term wxt
set key above
set datafile separator comma
plot [1.7:1.8] [-.1:1.1] 'foo.csv' with steps title columnhead"
```

Output:

[image: Zoom in at 1.7 to 1.8]

### Determine the PWM frequency with awk

As each line in your dataset represents a state switch, the switch frequency can be calculated by counting the switches and dividing by the difference in timestamps. This can be expressed in awk like this:

1. Split data into `winsz` chunks
2. For each chunk output `winsz / delta_t`

Note I ignore the first two lines of the csv file.

```
winsz=10

# Ignore heading and the first data point
tail -n+3 foo.csv | 

# Chunk data into winsz blocks
awk -F, 'NR % winsz == 0 { printf "\n" } 1' winsz=$winsz | 

# Output winsz
awk -F, 'NF > 2 { print winsz / ($(NF-1) - $1)}' RS= winsz=$winsz > foo-freq.txt
```

Here is a sample of `foo-freq.txt`:

```
6.294413875000000 1237.47
6.303694208333334 1194.89
6.313335750000000 1150.17
6.323380625000000 1103.85
6.333885375000000 1055.28
6.344918833333334 1004.47
6.356571500000000 950.826
6.368958500000001 894.181
6.382239458333333 833.608
6.396642625000000 768.32
```

You can plot this with the following Gnuplot code:

```gnuplot
set xlabel 'Time (s)'
set ylabel 'Frequency (Hz)'
plot 'foo-freq.txt' with lines
```

Result:

[image: PWM frequency plot]

### Determine the duty cycle with awk

I know you did not ask for it, but here is how you can determine the duty cycle of the PWM with `awk`. You probably need to use GNU awk with multi-precision support, as you have 14 decimals in the sample timestamps.

*duty-cycle.awk*

```awk
NR == 1 { 
  start_time = time_stamp = $1
  next
} 

# Count the length of time the signal is 0 and 1 respectiviely
$2 == 0 { len0 += $1-time_stamp }
$2 == 1 { len1 += $1-time_stamp }

# Remember previous timestamp
{ time_stamp = $1 }

# How frequently to calculate and output the duty cycle
NR % winsz == 0 { 
  delta_t = time_stamp - start_time
  print len0 / delta_t, len1 / delta_t
  start_time = time_stamp
  len0 = len1 = 0
}
```

Run it like this on your data:

```
tail -n+3 foo.csv | awk -M -F, -f duty-cycle.awk winsz=50 > duty-cycle.txt
```

Result:

[image: Plot of the calculated duty cycle]

### Datafile for future reference

I have uploaded the datafile to a [separate location](http://toggle.be/stackexchange/foo.csv) for future reference.

Comment: This is an interesting lesson about working with data. Maybe the *`Datafile for future reference`* part (though a reasonable idea to *do* first) should better not open the answer, it looks a little distracting... BTW congrats for 20K :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was intended, but the output of your signal simply oscillates between 0 and 1. I tried

```
import numpy as np
a = np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',')    #Using numpy to directly read csv file into numpy array. Also, I renamed the csv file to test.csv
a=a[1:]    #To remove the headers

print(np.nonzero(a[::2, 1]))
print(np.nonzero(a[1::2, 1]-1))
```

both yield empty lists, indicating all even positions have the value 1 and all odd indices have 0. That is why you see the mushed up plot.

So taking the mean of 1/4th the x-span(for four stages) and rendering it would be meaningless. So the only option you would be left with is to plot only a very small sub-section of your csv file

That can be easily done with just (assuming you want to plot from the 10th to the 20th value)

```
plt.plot( a[10:20,0], a[10:20,1])
```

[image]

An observation: although y-value jumps between 0 and 1 alternatively, x-value does not change in any pattern

Comment: Welll the signal is a PWM signal,   So i was expection 1 and 0 postions

Comment: So you wanted a square wave type plot, with the duty cycle representation, etc?

Comment: Yes.. that would be nice.